# org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: - Error selenium Java TestNG

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Below is the script which i am trying to use to add a new user -

```
 package pages;

import static org.testng.AssertJUnit.assertEquals;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import appSetup_Maven.test.BaseClass;
import appSetup_Maven.test.GenerateData;

public class AddCustomer extends BaseClass {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void before() {
        new GenerateData();
    }

    @Test(priority = 0)

    public void addCustomerPageNavigation() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Login();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sidebar-menu']/ul/li[3]/a/span[1]")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sidebar-menu']/ul/li[3]/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(
                By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/button")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(
                By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li/a"))
                .click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Organization_org_name']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(30));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_org_trading_name']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomString(20));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_org_number']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomNumber(10));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_phone_number']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomString(20));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //WebElement ListCountry = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_fk_country_codes_id']"));
        //Select country = new Select(ListCountry);
        //country.deselectByVisibleText("India");

        //WebElement ListState = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_fk_country_codes_id']"));
        //Select state = new Select(ListState);
        //country.deselectByVisibleText("Assam");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_address_street']']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomString(20));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_address_line2']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomString(20));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_address_suburb']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomString(20));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_address_postalcode']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomString(20));

        //WebElement NumEmp = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_numberOfEmployees']"));
        //Select Emp = new Select(NumEmp);
        //country.deselectByVisibleText("5-10");

        //WebElement NumUsr = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_totalUserSize']"));
        //Select Usr = new Select(NumUsr);
        //country.deselectByVisibleText("5-10");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*.//*[@id='Organization_domain_name']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomString(20));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Users_first_name']")).sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomString(20));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Users_last_name']")).sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomString(20));

        WebElement Role = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Users_fk_business_role_id']"));
        Select Usrrole = new Select(Role);
        //country.deselectByVisibleText("Other");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Users_username']")).sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomString(20));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='confirm-username']")).sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomString(20));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Users_password']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(30));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='re-password']")).sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(30)); // fail

        WebElement rListCountry = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_fk_country_codes_id']"));
        Select ccountry = new Select(rListCountry);
        //country.deselectByVisibleText("India");

        WebElement TimeZone = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_fk_country_codes_id']"));
        Select Time = new Select(TimeZone);
        //country.deselectByVisibleText("Asia/Kolkata");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='OrganizationBillingDetails_first_name']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(30));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='OrganizationBillingDetails_last_name']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(30));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='OrganizationBillingDetails_email']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateEmail(10));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='users-form']/div/div/div[5]/div/h2/div/ins"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateEmail(10));

        WebElement dListCountry = driver
                .findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='OrganizationBillingDetails_fk_country_codes_id']"));
        Select acountry = new Select(dListCountry);
        //country.deselectByVisibleText("India");

        WebElement aListState = driver
                .findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='OrganizationBillingDetails_fk_country_subdivisions_id']"));
        Select astate = new Select(aListState);
        //country.deselectByVisibleText("Assam");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='OrganizationBillingDetails_street']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(30));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='OrganizationBillingDetails_address_line2']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(30));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='OrganizationBillingDetails_city']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(30));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='OrganizationBillingDetails_postal_code']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(30));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='users-form']/div/div/div[7]/div[2]/div[2]/input[1]")).click();
        assertEquals("Success", driver.getTitle());

    }

}
```

Below is the class that I am using for generating random data -

```
package appSetup_Maven.test;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

public class GenerateData {

    public static String generateRandomString(int length) {
        return RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(length);
    }

    public static String generateRandomNumber(int length) {
        return RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(length);
    }

    public static String generateRandomAlphaNumeric(int length) {
        return RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(length);
    }

    public static String generateStringWithAllobedSplChars(int length, String allowdSplChrs) {
        String allowedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" + // alphabets
                "1234567890" + // numbers
                allowdSplChrs;
        return RandomStringUtils.random(length, allowedChars);
    }

    public static String generateEmail(int length) {
        String allowedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" + // alphabets
                "1234567890" + // numbers
                "_-."; // special characters
        String email = "";
        String temp = RandomStringUtils.random(length, allowedChars);
        email = temp.substring(0, temp.length() - 9) + "@test.org";
        return email;
    }

    public String generateUrl(int length) {
        String allowedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" + // alphabets
                "1234567890" + // numbers
                "_-."; // special characters
        String url = "";
        String temp = RandomStringUtils.random(length, allowedChars);
        url = temp.substring(0, 3) + "." + temp.substring(4, temp.length() - 4) + "."
                + temp.substring(temp.length() - 3);
        return url;
    }
}
```

Below is the add customer page navigation code. Would request you to please review apologies for the delay -

```
package pages;

import static org.testng.AssertJUnit.assertEquals;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import appSetup_Maven.test.BaseClass;
import appSetup_Maven.test.GenerateData;

public class AddCustomer extends BaseClass {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void before() {
        new GenerateData();
    }

    @Test(priority = 0)

    public void addCustomerPageNavigation() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Login();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sidebar-menu']/ul/li[3]/a/span[1]")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sidebar-menu']/ul/li[3]/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(
                By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/button")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(
                By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li/a"))
                .click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Organization_org_name']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(30));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_org_trading_name']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomString(20));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_org_number']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomNumber(10));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_phone_number']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomString(20));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //WebElement ListCountry = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_fk_country_codes_id']"));
        //Select country = new Select(ListCountry);
        //country.deselectByVisibleText("India");

        //WebElement ListState = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_fk_country_codes_id']"));
        //Select state = new Select(ListState);
        //country.deselectByVisibleText("Assam");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_address_street']']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomString(20));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_address_line2']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomString(20));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_address_suburb']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomString(20));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_address_postalcode']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomString(20));

        //WebElement NumEmp = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_numberOfEmployees']"));
        //Select Emp = new Select(NumEmp);
        //country.deselectByVisibleText("5-10");

        //WebElement NumUsr = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_totalUserSize']"));
        //Select Usr = new Select(NumUsr);
        //country.deselectByVisibleText("5-10");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*.//*[@id='Organization_domain_name']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomString(20));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Users_first_name']")).sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomString(20));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Users_last_name']")).sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomString(20));

        WebElement Role = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Users_fk_business_role_id']"));
        Select Usrrole = new Select(Role);
        //country.deselectByVisibleText("Other");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Users_username']")).sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomString(20));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='confirm-username']")).sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomString(20));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Users_password']")).sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(30));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='re-password']")).sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(30)); // fail

        WebElement rListCountry = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_fk_country_codes_id']"));
        Select ccountry = new Select(rListCountry);
        //country.deselectByVisibleText("India");

        /*String email = genData.generateEmail(30);
        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(email);
        driver.findElement(By.id("emailconfirm")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("emailconfirm")).sendKeys(email);
        */
        WebElement TimeZone = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Organization_fk_country_codes_id']"));
        Select Time = new Select(TimeZone);
        //country.deselectByVisibleText("Asia/Kolkata");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='OrganizationBillingDetails_first_name']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(30));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='OrganizationBillingDetails_last_name']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(30));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='OrganizationBillingDetails_email']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateEmail(10));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='users-form']/div/div/div[5]/div/h2/div/ins"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateEmail(10));

        WebElement dListCountry = driver
                .findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='OrganizationBillingDetails_fk_country_codes_id']"));
        Select acountry = new Select(dListCountry);
        //country.deselectByVisibleText("India");

        WebElement aListState = driver
                .findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='OrganizationBillingDetails_fk_country_subdivisions_id']"));
        Select astate = new Select(aListState);
        //country.deselectByVisibleText("Assam");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='OrganizationBillingDetails_street']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(30));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='OrganizationBillingDetails_address_line2']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(30));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='OrganizationBillingDetails_city']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(30));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='OrganizationBillingDetails_postal_code']"))
                .sendKeys(GenerateData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(30));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='users-form']/div/div/div[7]/div[2]/div[2]/input[1]")).click();
        assertEquals("Success", driver.getTitle());

    }

}
```

Below is the base class would request you to please review -

```
package appSetup_Maven.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class BaseClass {
    protected static WebDriver driver;
    protected static PropertiesGrabber properties = PropertiesGrabber.getInstance();

    @BeforeSuite
    public void Setup() throws IOException {
        try {
            properties.init("E:\\Git Repos\\n2s-sun-selenium-automation\\datadriven.properties");
            initDriver();
            maximize();
            getDriver().get(properties.get("url"));
            waitEle();
            Reporter.log("===Browser Started==", true);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Reporter.log("Error::::" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void initDriver() {
        if (null != driver) {
            return;
        }
        if (properties.exists("browserName", "firefox")) {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            return;
        }

        if (properties.exists("browserName", "chrome")) {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            return;
        }

        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }

    public void FullScreenWait() {
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    protected WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public void Login() throws IOException {
        try {
            getDriver().get(properties.get("url"));
            getElement(".//*[@id='LoginForm_username']").sendKeys("avinash@abcd.com");
            getElement(".//*[@id='LoginForm_password']").sendKeys("abcd");
            getElement(".//*[@id='login-form']/button").click();
            System.out.println("==Logged in==");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("==may be Logged in== " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    protected WebElement getElement(String xPath) {
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath));
    }

    public void GenData() {
        GenerateData genData;
        genData = new GenerateData();
    }

    protected void maximize() {
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }

    protected void waitEle() {

        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    @AfterTest
    public void close() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void Close() {
        // driver.quit();

    }
}
```

Error message that I am getting same as the title but below are the exact stack trace -

```
> Tests run: 15, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed:
> 115.588 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
>     addCustomerPageNavigation(pages.AddCustomer)  Time elapsed: 4.641 sec  <<< FAILURE!
>     org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
>     Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8e7ca8e37638dc3091b2440b90a1d8686f', time: '2015-02-27
> 09:10:26'
>     System info: host: 'DESKTOP-1AKPPH7', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version:
> '1.8.0_111'
>     Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>       at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:72)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:125)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:319)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:126)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:72)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:133)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.execute(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:165)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:362)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:572)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.access$100(FirefoxDriver.java:73)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$1$1.implicitlyWait(FirefoxDriver.java:219)
>       at pages.AddCustomer.addCustomerPageNavigation(AddCustomer.java:28) 

>     Results :
>     
>     Failed tests: 
>       AddCustomer.addCustomerPageNavigation:28 » UnreachableBrowser Error communicat...
>     
>     Tests run: 15, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Questions -<br/>
1. How do I fix the above error and why and in which case do we get this error.<br/>
2. There are issues in this script, such as the randomly generated e-mails don't match, How can I do fix this ?
```

Comment: The exception occurred in `addCustomerPageNavigation` in `AddCustomer`. The code you posted has nothing to do with the exception, please post the relevant code.

Comment: Thats the code I am using mate, because i don't have any class called addCustomerPageNavigation in AddCustomer

Comment: `addCustomerPageNavigation` is a method, `AddCustomer` is the class. It very clear from the stacktrace: `at pages.AddCustomer.addCustomerPageNavigation(AddCustomer.java:28)`

Comment: done sir :) apologies i missed it

Comment: You didn't provide the code for `Login()` but I'm guessing you have `driver.close()` or `driver.quit()`  there or in other place between the driver initialization and `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait`.

Comment: Sorry sir just saw your answer but yes you are bang on with the solution, that what i found out just now ! and fixed it and all well now, wished i saw your post earlier ..would have saved a lot of effort. Thanks again for your help and looking into my query its very much appreciated.

Comment: Guy - I have updated the code to above please let me know incase there are any other things that I can correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every initialized driver should be either close quit after the test is completed.
driver.close will close the current browser window where the driver focus is. And driver.quit will close all the browser sessions/windows opened by this driver.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the code for Login() but I'm guessing you have driver.close() or driver.quit() there or in other place between the driver initialization and